# Unable to upload image in wordpress admin page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add a form to upload images in the user profile admin page in wordpress, i had tried this code before and it was working fine in a normal php page but when i tried it in this wordpress function it is not working.

Can someone help with this?

```
function image_up_gall(){
?>
  <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
  </form>

<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'image_up_gall');
add_action('show_user_profile', 'image_up_gall');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this bellow

```
if (isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {

    $destination = $_POST["dir"];

    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $error = $_FILES['file']['error'];

    //echo $name;
    //echo $tmp_name;
    //echo $error;

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destination.$name);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all `edit_user_profile` and `show_user_profile` action hooks don't have to save the image, you can just add a field there. So

```
function image_up_gall(){
?>

    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
 <?php
}
add_action('edit_user_profile', 'image_up_gall');
add_action('show_user_profile', 'image_up_gall');
```

It is because WordPress has its own form tag already, just make sure that it has  `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Second step, using `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` you can save the form/upload imag, to do so, use this code:

```
function save_profile_fields( $user_id ) {
$target_dir = "uploads/"; // I recommend to use wp_upload_dir() to get the correct path
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            // here the image is uploaded and we can save it to user profile with:
            update_usermeta( $user_id, 'profile_pic', $target_file );
    }
}

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_profile_fields' );
```

But I recommend you to use WordPress default media library to do that, there is a lot of code, so I better give you a link to the tutorial: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/customizable-media-uploader.html

Comment: Can you describe how?

Comment: The image didn't upload.